# load css files after $.ajax complete

Tags: jquery, css

i am getting content from server by $.ajax. And those content is html strings, they have their owen style, following is my codes:

```
 <script src="jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="Default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dataStr = "indexOfStart=" + 0;
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#idgetData").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "http://localhost:1897/Content/Services/Service1.asmx/GetArticlesDuring",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: { indexOfStart: 0, indexOfEnd: 20 },
                jsonp: 'back',
                success: function (result) {
                    var res = decodeURIComponent(result.Result);
                    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = res;

                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    targetDiv = $("#data");
                    if (errorThrown || textStatus == "error" || textStatus == "parsererror" || textStatus == "notmodified") {
                        targetDiv.replaceWith("请求数据时发生错误！");
                        return;
                    }
                    if (textStatus == "timeout") {
                        targetDiv.replaceWith("请求数据超时！");
                        return;
                    }
                },
                complete: function () {
                    //addStyle("Default.css");
                    //addStyle("all.css");
                    document.write('<link href="Default.css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="all.css" rel="stylesheet" />');
                }
            });
        });
    });
function addStyle(stylePath) {
        var container = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        var addStyle = document.createElement("link");
        addStyle.rel = "stylesheet";
        addStyle.type = "text/css";
        addStyle.href = stylePath;
        container.appendChild(addStyle);
    }
```

the problem is the content's style can not be loaded and work,
can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need to load the styles after the request finishes, as once css is loaded, it'll apply styles for new elements as well. But you could append the css stylesheet to the head in the `complete` event handler if you wanted to.

Comment: yes,you are right. i find the problem is in the content strings with html in it i got,before the style classes name, there is "+"(plus).it is because in C# code for send content, i used "Server.UrlEncode(string)", it will cause "+" problem. and i find the solution as that : in c# code, i use "Microsoft.JScript.GlobalObject.encodeURIComponent(string)" for encode html content, in client js code, i use "decodeURIComponent" to decode. so perfect way,it is OK now. and thank U so much!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help, it is no problem

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you just load the styles again that you already have. If the new HTML content has new CSS styles (i.e. they are neither in `Default.css` nor in `all.css`), you need to put them in a new stylesheet or a new inline `<style>` element and add that to document.

Comment: thank U , i find the solution,  and i find some interesting things, you can get it by seeing the first answer's comment!

Comment: Your nearly 7 year old answer helped, TY.